# How do I control the z index of a drop down menu in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a drop down menu to go behind the OutlinedTextField

I wish to do this
[correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S67sy.png)

This is how it looks currently
[current app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFPHd.png)

I have tried putting zIndex, and updating to androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha10. I am also using the workaround for the width of ExposedDropDownMenu by changing it to DropDownMenu and using .exposedDropdownSize() on the DropDownMenu

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun WalletDropDown(
    viewModel: BookViewModel,
    transactionType: TransactionType
) {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = state.isWalletExpanded && state.transactionType == transactionType.value,
        onExpandedChange = {
            viewModel.updateWalletExpanded(!state.isWalletExpanded)
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = state.wallet,
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.updateNoteState(it)
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
            ),
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(
                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                    includeFontPadding = false
                )
            ),
            trailingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = if (state.isWalletExpanded) R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_up else R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down),
                    contentDescription = "Dropdown",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(24.dp)
                )
            },
            readOnly = true,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp)
                .padding(bottom = 5.dp)
                .menuAnchor()
                .zIndex(2f)
        )
        MaterialTheme(
            shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(
                extraSmall = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)
            )
        ) {
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = state.isWalletExpanded && state.transactionType == transactionType.value,
                onDismissRequest = {
                    viewModel.updateWalletExpanded(false)
                },
                properties = PopupProperties(
                    focusable = true,
                    dismissOnClickOutside = true,
                    dismissOnBackPress = true
                ),
                offset = DpOffset(x = 0.dp, y = (-50).dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .exposedDropdownSize(true)
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .border(
                        width = 1.dp,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(24.dp)
                    )
                    .zIndex(1f)

            ) {
                DropdownMenuItem(text = {}, onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
                WalletDropDownItem(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    icon = R.drawable.bca,
                    walletName = "BCA",
                    money = "Rp 1,000,000.00"
                )
                WalletDropDownItem(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    icon = R.drawable.dana,
                    walletName = "Dana",
                    money = "Rp 3,000,000.00"
                )
                WalletDropDownItem(
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    icon = R.drawable.gopay,
                    walletName = "Gopay",
                    money = "Rp 500,000.00"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WalletDropDownItem(
    viewModel: BookViewModel,
    icon: Int,
    walletName: String,
    money: String
) {
    DropdownMenuItem(
        leadingIcon = {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = icon),
                contentDescription = "wallet",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(24.dp)
            )
        },
        text = {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = walletName,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
                )
                Text(
                    text = money,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
                )
            }
        },
        onClick = {
            viewModel.updateWalletState(walletName)
            viewModel.updateWalletExpanded(false)
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .zIndex(1f)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.material3/material3/1.0.0-alpha08-source/androidx/compose/material3/AndroidMenu.android.kt.html) says:

> A DropdownMenu behaves similarly to a Popup, and will use the
> position of the parent layout to position itself on screen. Commonly a
> DropdownMenu will be placed in a Box with a sibling that will be used
> as the 'anchor'. Note that a DropdownMenu by itself will not take up
> any space in a layout, as the menu is displayed in a separate window,
> on top of other content.

So it will always be drawn on top of other content. In case you find some workaround, please share it, I'm sure others (including myself) would appreciate it!